# How to create intent for selecting multiple images from gallery?

Tags: android, tomtom

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

This intent should allow the user to browse and select multiple images from his device. It should work from Android 4.3 – but it does not work on the TomTom Bridge I'm developing for.

I've found undocumented Intents for multi-select galleries that work for Samsung devices (http://coder-jeff.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-pick-multiple-files-from.html).

Anything similar on the TomTom?

Comment: As far as I know, EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE is an intent created for explicit use when multi pick is supported, and the support for it depends on the developer of the gallery app.

Comment: The gallery on the device DOES support multi pick – only when called via intent it does not. I suppose reverse engineering the gallery will reveal what the undocumented parameter is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/zfdang/android-multiple-images-selector) for multi selection

In gradle

```
compile 'com.zfdang.multiple-images-selector:multiple-images-selector:1.1.3'
```

Here is the other [library](https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect) for multi selection from gallery.